# How to simplify cases given with Piecewise function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

MMA gives me an answer in the form
$$ \begin{cases}
f(k_1) & k_1=k\\
0 & else
\end{cases} $$

which is obviously just $f(k)$. Can I make MMA simplify this expression to $f(k)$?

The `FullForm` code I get is
`Piecewise[List[List[f[k1], Equal[k1, k]]], 0]`.

P.S. I am aware (Full)Simplify or Reduce doesn't work here since Piecewise is a function and isn't equal to $f(k)$ everywhere.

Comment: this function could't be symplifyed to f(k) in general, for all other cases? such as flattening of the nested piecewise there is a built-in function `PiecewiseExpand`

Comment: Tell Simplify k1==k. Simplify[Piecewise[List[List[f[k1],Equal[k1,k]]],0], k1==k]/.k1->k gives you f[k] p.s. Thank you for the FullForm

Comment: @Bill please consider posting an answer :)